# Why do two inline-blocks next to each other use more than their total width?

Tags: css, layout, width, html

Sorry if the question is badly worded.

I'm trying to fit two span's next to each other.
Their common container has `100%` width, so I thought that giving them widths `5%` and `95%` will work, but it does not. I also set the margin and padding to zero for everything.

please see the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q5ZX9/

and here is the code of the fiddle above:

HTML (body):

```
<span id='outer'>
    <h1>Outer</h1>
    <span id='left'>
        left
    </span>
    <span id='right'>
        right
    </span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#outer
{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#left
{
    width:5%;
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(200,0,0,0.5);
}
#right
{
    width:95%;
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(00,0,200,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#left{
  float: left;
  width:5%;
  display:inline-block;
  background:rgba(200,0,0,0.5);
}
#right{
  float: left;
  width:95%;
  display:inline-block;
  background:rgba(00,0,200,0.5);
}
```

Comment: Yes ! I've gone as far as putting float:right; to right, and everything else identical, but haven't tried that. Thanks !

It would also be great if you say something about why does it not work without floating ?

Comment: Block level elements generally begin on new lines and because of that you must float them left or right with proportional size to get them next to each other.

Comment: Ok, but these are inline-block, so should'nt they be already doing this ?

Comment: No, I said "block-level" and by that I also mean `inline-block`, you could set just `inline` then they would be next to each other but in that case they wouldn't' accept width property. All in all it's best to gave them a float, like when you create navigation list, also block level, you set e.g. `ul li { float: left; ... }`. If you want example with `display:table-cell;` check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/f9AyW/).

Comment: OK then. I will remember this solution I hope :) Thanks for your help !

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw - While the answer is fine (if that's the way you want to go, there are other solutions), the explanation is a little awry. [`inline-block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) elements are "block containers" but they themselves are "inline-level" not "block-level".

Comment: Yes, `inline-block` elements are inline `block` containers, of course if they have a parent element and to put them next to each other we can use `float` property or write HTML code in the same line which is little messy by my opinion, but of course for every problem almost always exist multiple solutions.